# AWS S3 Interface Endpoint with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

So I'm trying to create S3 Interface endpoint with DNS enabled but without "Enable private DNS only for inbound endpoint".
In AWS DOCs and in boto3 DOCs its described as "PrivateDnsOnlyForInboundEndpoint"
but I don't see anything regarding this in Terraform DOCs.

When I'm using the "private_dns_enabled = true"
I'm getting **InvalidParamter: To set PrivateDnsOnlyForInboundEndpoint to true, to VPC-XXXX must have a gateway endpoint for this service.**

As I mentioned earlier I do not need PrivateDnsOnlyForInboundEndpoint, So I'm trying to disable this option without any success.

In AWS console the option does exists - (as shown in the picture)
[image: AWS EP DNS EDIT]

Terraform code

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3_interface" {
vpc_id              = data.aws_vpc.vpc_id.id
service_name        = "com.amazonaws.${var.aws_region}.s3"
vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
subnet_ids          = [data.aws_subnet.mgmt_private_subnet.id]
security_group_ids  = [data.aws_security_group.sg.id]
private_dns_enabled = true
dns_options {
  dns_record_ip_type = "ipv4"

}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How is this related to terraform? Is there any terraform code? If so, please add it to the question.

Comment: Also, can you share the error you see when you run the terraform code

Comment: I added the TF code.
it is related as it does not have the option to disable privateDnsOnlyForInboundEndpoint as a tf code.

the error is available in the post

Comment: Well, have you enabled the options from the screenshot in the VPC you want to use?

Comment: @MarkoE The screenshot is just for example. I`m trying to do same with TF code.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do is not possible.
For interface endpoints you need you have to use a inbound reslover endpoint to get the private DNS to work. But if you go with a gateway endpoint instead it should work.

Read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20configure%20private%20DNS%20with%20an%20inbound%20Resolver%20endpoint%20only%20for%20interface%20endpoints%20for%20Amazon%20S3.%20If%20you%20do%20not%20have%20a%20gateway%20endpoint%20for%20Amazon%20S3%20and%20you%20select%20Enable%20private%20DNS%20only%20for%20inbound%20endpoint%2C%20you%27ll%20receive%20an%20error%20when%20you%20attempt%20the%20final%20step%20in%20this%20procedure.)

Comment: I see, but still.. I can do it over the console.. So I dont understand why it cannot be done via terraform.

Comment: in the picture you haven't ticked in the PrivateDnsOnlyForInboundEndpoint box. And I think you may have created a gateway endpoint in the console or a interface endpoint but not with the settings you think.

Comment: I did not check the PrivateDnsOnlyForInboundEndpoint  on purpose. I only wish to enable private DNS. I say it again. when I tries to enable it via console everything works. when I try to do the same via TF it doesn't work for resason I stated before.

Answer (score 0):

So after checking.. here is the answer.
it turns out that PrivateDnsOnlyForInboundEndpoint is a new feature that is not yet exists in terraform.
You can view it here -
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/30041
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/amazon-s3-private-connectivity-on-premises-networks/

Thanks anyway (: